# javafxports HelloAndroid sample - only black screen on device

Tags: javafxports

I download JavaFX Android SDK version 8.60.7 from http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/get/

I install gradle 2.2

I build and install apk successfully on device.

But after start application I seen only black screen.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: "While you can download the JavaFX Mobile SDK’s from this page, we highly recommend using the jfxmobile gradle plugin". Why don't you install the Gluon plugin for your IDE? It will manage for you all the dependencies, and includes several templates that you can immediately deploy on your device. Also, in case of black screen, run on command line `adb logcat -v threadtime` to find about the possible exception when running your app.

Comment: Thanks, using Gluon plugin for NetBeans it is ok.